# CQRS/ES - handling projection errors

Tags: java, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

I'm working on a CQRS+ES system, mainly using the axon framework, but really this question applies to any implementation. So I have a command handler and 1 or more event handlers, running on different JVMs, containers etc, and at some point one of these handlers encounters an error.

We have two cases, an 'expected' business error and an 'unexpected' system error. As I understand it, we are now in an asynchronous handler, and the event is now a fact, so in reality we cannot directly rollback the command for neither case (as it could entail rolling it back in numerous other projections and break CQRS).

So my question is, should such an error be 'resolved' in an accounts ledger sort of way, i.e. by sending a new 'reversal' command that is then propagated to the projections in such a way that the event that failed is now resolved?

As an example, let's say we have a command that updates a customer's credit. The event is published, one projection updates its "total credits" statistic, another one publishes the update to some websocket for the UI and, finally, another one which maintains the credit state - and this last handler fails. Should we send a command for rolling back the business transaction, and again deduct the credit, update the websocket again, etc? And in case of axon is there some way in which this is captured as a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd state that the decision making whether taking an action, thus handling a command, is okay, should always lie with the Command Model/Aggregate. The aggregate being in an incorrect state to handle an action will typically lead to a 'business exception/error'.

If you'd make decisions upon event handling failing however, you're adding some decision making logic in a event handling service which in most cases it likely doesn't care about. It such an event handling services updates views/query models, but fails to do so, I'd argue that's not a valid reason to publish a 'compensating command' to your aggregate to 'rollback/undo the event'.

In your example you have a 'credit-state-maintainer', which I'd guess updates a query model. As such I'd deem the problem of dealing with the exception to lie within the service itself, not by performing a compensating action.

From an Axon Framework perspective, you could wrap your `CreditStateEventHandler` in a `TrackingEventProcessor` and trigger a reset on that event processor by calling the `TrackingEventProcessor#resetTokens()` function. This is taken the stance that the exception due to which your `CreditStateEventHandler` is due to faulty coding of course, otherwise a replay would result in the exact same exception.